# Run Android Failed reason package android.support.v4.net does not exist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

What's mean this error this error?

[image]

before this, i try to build with ./gradlew assembleRelease and got the error same, and so i just run "react-native run-android" and got the same error.

Comment: can you attach gradle file of your project?
attach this line may help:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'

Comment: not working with this dependency also.